# referencing properties that are yet to be defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects.  The objects reference properties that need to be examined.  However, the properties are optional and might not get passed.  This results in an error.

Here is a greatly simplified version of the code:

```
var build = {
    execute: function (type, data) {
        switch (type) {

            case  "fullName":
                return build.fullName(data);
        }
    },
    fullName: function(data){
        return data[0] + data[1]
    }
};

// assume this is the actual inbound data after parsing
var sample_event = {
    customer: {
        firstName: "bob",
        lastName: "smith",
        email: "a@example.com"
    }
};


function cleanStuff( event) {

    // potential inbound data

    var prospects = [
        {parent: "customer", type: build.fullName, newField: 'fullName',data: [event.customer.firstName, event.customer.middleName, event.customer.lastName]},
        {parent: "customer", type: build.fullName, newField:'fullName', data: [event.idontexist.firstName, event.seller.middleName, event.seller.lastName]}
    ];

    function calc(type, newField, calculationData) {
        var calculated = calculated || {};
        return calculated[newField] = build.execute(type, calculationData);
    }

    var filteredList = prospects.filter(function (x) {
        if (event[x.parent] !== undefined) {
            return x
        }
    });

    filteredList.forEach(function (item) {
        var type = item.type,
            fieldName = item.fieldName,
            data = item.data;

        calc(type, fieldName, data, event);

    });
}

cleanStuff(sample_event);
```

How does one go about referencing properties that don't exist?   I DO NOT want to create empty properties, or set them to null.  I want to simply avoid scrubbing them if they were not sent in to the app.

I could create the elements as Strings and parse them back to property paths at time of use but I think thats a bad approach.

I was also considering setting up a Proxy using ES6 but Chrome has yet update with the latest spec.

I'm using the 'prospects' array as a lookup table of sorts to say, "hey if this value is sent, do X to it".

Comment: Why are you referencing values that don't yet exist? That sounds like a problem with your design, to me.

Comment: I get an inbound JSON Post containing a bunch of optional data.  This array of "prospects" lists all values that may need some normalization/scrubbing. There is a "normalization" method elsewhere that takes the inbound data, checks against this "prospects" array and performs the "type" of normalization against the respective "data" .    I'm open to any suggestions on better design or patterns to follow.

Comment: So why is the piece of code trying to access the objects executing before the data exists? Could you please show how you do such access in order to have a [mcve]?

Comment: If you don't know whether a given property exists or not, then you write code to check if it exists and then behave in a safe way based on what you learned by checking if it exists.  Or, you make sure a property exists (creating it if needed and assigning a default value).  There's nothing else you can do.  Pick one of those options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using the newly introduced Proxy (ES6) works well here and allows me to set traps to handle these scenarios.   Very cool addition to JS, allows for a great level of abstraction.

```
function Event(event) {
    var proxy = new Proxy(event, {

        get: function (target, property) {
            if (property in target) {
                return target[property];
            } else {
                return " ";
            }
        }
    });

    return proxy;
}



var event = new Event(sample_event);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Babel (via Webpack or Browserify perhaps) to compile ES6 code, and problem solved?

Maybe you can use async functions with Promises that promise the data will eventually be available?